# im trying to create a foreign key with my sql but i keep having in a error

Tags: mysql

i have two table one has a primary key called idHotel i am making a second table and im trying to declare a foreign key which has idHotel reference
this my code what wrong with it

```
CREATE TABLE Evaluation(
DateEval date ,
Idhotel int  ,
NoteAccueil int,
NoteRest int,
NoteExtra int ,
FOREIGN key Idhotel REFERENCES hotel(Idhotel)
```

)

in case you want the reference table code here it is

[refrence table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf80d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below  code

```
CREATE TABLE Evaluation(
DateEval date ,
Idhotel int  ,
NoteAccueil int,
NoteRest int,
NoteExtra int ,
FOREIGN key (Idhotel) REFERENCES hotel(Idhotel));
```